# NoClassDefFoundError While using Eclipse Cloud Foundry Plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, cloud-foundry

So I have a maven project that I eventually build into a jar that looks like:

`C:\Users\myTest\TESTJAR-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

If I push to cloud foundry using command line it deploys fine:

`cf push newProject -p C:\Users\myTest\TESTJAR-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

However, when I trying deploying from Eclipse using the plugin, I get the following

'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory'

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

POM.xml

```
`  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>test.myTest</groupId>
<artifactId>TESTJAR</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>   

<name>test</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency> 
<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>



<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic  --> 
<dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId> 
<artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId> 
<version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.lalyos</groupId>
<artifactId>jfiglet</artifactId>
<version>0.0.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
<artifactId>guava</artifactId>
<version>19.0</version> 
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
<artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
<version>1.4.8</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>  
<groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>

<exclusions>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions> 

</dependency>

<dependency> 
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId> 
<artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId> 
<version>4.0</version> 
</dependency>

</dependencies>
 <build>
 <plugins>

 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.3</version>
  <configuration>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>

  <archive>
  <manifest>
    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
    <mainClass>com.myTest.Main</mainClass>
  </manifest>
  </archive>

  <descriptorRefs>
    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
  </descriptorRefs>

  </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
  </project>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Jar-packaged applications can be pushed to Cloud Foundry using Eclipse Cloud Foundry Tools (CFT) in two ways:

1. Specifying a manifest YAML file at top level in your Eclipse Maven project that points to jar in the file system that you want to push, using the “path" attribute. For example, in a workspace project,  MyTestMavenProject, you’d have something like:

MyTestMavenProject/manifest.yml

with the contents of the manifest file

```
---   
applications:
- name: testjarapp
  path: C:\Users\myTest\TESTJAR-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Drag and drop the project containing this manifest file to a Cloud Foundry target in the Eclipse Servers view.

2. Drag/drop the Maven project without a manifest file, and CFT will automatically package the application prior to pushing to Cloud Foundry. However, this mechanism has some known issues for jar-packaged apps. In some cases, the project needs to be refreshed manually prior to drag/drop:

   - Refresh the project (typically F5)
   - Right-click on project: Maven -> Update Project
   - Drag/drop the Maven project onto the CF target in Servers view again to see if it deploys correctly

There is a bug that is tracking the issue here:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=495814

CFT milestones are released roughly every 6 weeks, so the next milestone after Eclipse Neon (4.6) will have various bug fixes and improvements for the deployment of jar-packaged applications.